# How to escape only certain characters

Tags: php, regex, escaping

php function `preg_quote` escapes these characters  `. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -`

Could you please suggest what I could use to escape these characters: `+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : /`

---

**Edited** (as requested by "on hold"):

I'm implementing a `Solr` search and it says:

> Solr gives the following characters special meaning when they appear
>   in a query:
>   + - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : /
>
> To make Solr interpret any of these characters literally, rather as a special character, precede the
>   character with a backslash character .

Comment: Great. You know what `preg_quote()` is. Now, please, read it's parameters list with their description

Comment: Alma: if I understood it correctly, I can specify delimiter in this function to have it also escaped, but it does not help my situation as this delimiter will not release other default characters that `preg_quote` function escapes from being escaped.

Comment: You have been fallen under the X/Y Problem. Instead search for string functions in PHP, there is one you're looking for: http://php.net/addcslashes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may help you:

```
<?php
$subject = "+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ \" ~ * ? : /";
$result = preg_replace('%([+\-&|!(){}[\]^"~*?:/]+)%', '\\\\$1', $subject);
echo $result;
?>
```

http://ideone.com/EYV1ID

Comment: Actually, how can you "escape", for example, `||` ? It's __two__ symbols, not one. Thus, what will be the difference with standard `preg_quote()` parameters?

Comment: @dmit In my view this solution is incorrect. For instance it will escape `&` even when it is not part of `&&`. Same with a lone `|`. To address that, see my solution.

Comment: zx81: you are right, it does behave that way. I did not notice it at at first.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the best approach but will work:

```
str_replace('+','\+',$MyString);
str_replace('-','\-',$MyString);
...............................;
...............................;
```

Comment: Well, at least use a `foreach` statement and an array to make it look a bit less bloated.

Answer (score 0):

Working function

```
function escapeWildcards($s){
    $escapeChars = [ '%', '_'];
    foreach ($escapeChars as $escapeChar){
        $s = str_replace($escapeChar, '\\'.$escapeChar, $s);
    }
    return $s;
}
```