# Use preg_quote but keep certain special regular expression characters

Tags: php, regex

The preg_quote function allows specifying an additional delimiter to escape. But for purposes of replacements is there an alternative to also specify delimiters **not** to escape?

For example, I wish to escape everything (including the additional delimiter `"/"`) except `"*"` and `"\"`.

Kind of like:

```
$str = 'Replace/this line $15 #1 except \w* {';
$str = preg_quote_except($str, '/', '\*');
// Should be identical to:
$str = 'Replace\/this line \$15 \#1 except \w* \{';
```

**Update**

While I appreciate your effort to mark this as a duplicate merely seconds after it was asked, it's really not a duplicate of [How to escape only certain characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23265654/how-to-escape-only-certain-characters). The user there wanted **only certain** characters while I want **all except** some. I don't want to manually manage what to escape (BTW, remember PHP once in a while adds new characters to escape).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can undo the undesired escapes.

```
$str = preg_quote($str, '/');
$str = str_replace(['\\*', '\\\\'], ['*', '\\'], $str);
```

This can be a function:

```
function preg_quote_except($str, $except, $delim = NULL) {
    $str = preg_quote($str, $delim);
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($except); $i++) {
        $from[] = '\\' . $except[$i];
        $to[] = $except[$i];
    }
    return str_replace($from, $to, $str);
}
```

Then you would call it like:

```
$str = preg_quote_except($str, '\\*', '/');
```

I moved the delimiter parameter to the end so it can be optional.